# Código em java não se executa os comandos

Tags: java

Já entrei em vários sites buscando por essa pergunta porém não obtive o resultado, ao executar o meu código ele inicia-se normalmente porém após inserir o número correspondente ao comando ele simplesmente fecha como se tivesse terminado o programa. Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Estou tentando fazer uma Televisão e um Controle Remoto.

Aparece apenas os textos das Classe Main e não se executa mais nada ao inserir o número correspondente

SOU BEM INICIANTE EM JAVA

Classe Main Abaixo:

```java
import java.io.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
      BufferedReader reader;
      reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

      Television t = new Television();
    
      System.out.println("\t\tRemoteCtrl");
      System.out.println("\t 1 - Ligar");
      System.out.println("\t 2 - Aumentar o Vol.");
      System.out.println("\t 3 - Diminuir o Vol.");
      System.out.println("\t 4 - Próximo Canal");
      System.out.println("\t 5 - Canal Anterior");
      System.out.println("\t 6 - Desligar");
      System.out.println("Opções:");
      String reply = reader.readLine();
      int op = Integer.parseInt(reply);
  
      switch (op) {
      case 1:
        if (t.isOn()) {
          System.out.println("A Televisão já está ligada");
        } else {
          t.setOn(true);
        }
      break;
      case 2:
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

Classe Television:

```java
public class Television {
  int volume, channel;
  String marca;
  boolean on;

  public int getVolume() {
    return volume;
  }

  public void setVolume(int volume){
    this.volume = volume;
  }

  public int getChannel(){
    return channel;
  }

  public void setChannel(int channel){
    this.channel = channel;
  }

  public String getMarca(){
    return marca;
  }

  public void setMarca(String marca) {
    this.marca = marca;
  }

  public boolean isOn(){
    return on;
  }

  public void setOn(boolean on){
    this.on = on;
  }
}
```

clsse RemoteCtrl:

```java
public class RemoteCtrl {
  int maxVolume = 100, maxChannel = 10;

  Television t = new Television(); 
  
  void volumeUp() {
    int volume = t.getVolume();

    if(volume < maxVolume) {
      volume++;
      t.setVolume(volume);
    } else {
      System.out.println("Maior Volume Possível Atingido");
    }
  }

  void downVolume() {
  }

  void nextChannel() {
  }

  void previousChannel() {
  }
}
```

Comment: Importante você [edit] sua pergunta e explicar de maneira objetiva e pontual a dificuldade encontrada com um [mcve] do problema em vez do código original. Para entender que tipo de pergunta serve para o site e, consequentemente, evitar fechamentos e negativações vale a pena ler [O que é o Stack Overflow](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7256/70) e o [Guia de sobrevivência (resumido) do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/70).

Comment: Este comportamento está correto. Além da lista de opções, o único texto que vc tá tentando imprimir é "A Televisão já está ligada", só que este texto só será impresso caso a televisão já esteja ligada, se ela estiver desligada, que é o caso, vc só liga e encerra o programa. Experimenta colocar um `println()` acima daquele `setOn()` para vc ver como ele executa certinho.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Aparentemente você está começando com programação agora, o problema principal do seu código é que não há um laço de repetição portanto o código vai executar linearmente até o fim da função `Main` e terminar.

Envelopar a sua Main com um while condicionado por uma variável boolean resolveria isso.

```
    System.out.println("\t\tRemoteCtrl");
    System.out.println("\t 1 - Ligar");
    System.out.println("\t 2 - Aumentar o Vol.");
    System.out.println("\t 3 - Diminuir o Vol.");
    System.out.println("\t 4 - Próximo Canal");
    System.out.println("\t 5 - Canal Anterior");
    System.out.println("\t 6 - Desligar");
    System.out.println("Opções:");
    String reply = reader.readLine();
    int op = Integer.parseInt(reply);
    boolean run = true;
    while(run){
        switch (op){
            case 1:
            if (t.isOn()){
                System.out.println("A Televisão já está ligada");
        
            }else{
                t.setOn(true);
            }
            break;

            case 2:
            break;
            case 6:
            if(t.isOn()) t.setOn(false);
            run = false;
            break;
    }

  }
```